# Drupal paths in themes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

On certain pages drupal_get_path isn't working correctly (or it is and I've got the wrong function)
The base path is wrong

Example:
Image is supposed to be at 
http://domain.com/sites/all/modules/pecapture/images/headline_dontmissout.jpg

But when on 
http://domain.com/node/9

The URL is
http://domain.com/**node**/sites/all/modules/pecapture/images/headline_dontmissout.jpg

The same happens on the page
http://domain.com/**admin/build**/ and block edit page

How do I get the right path?

Comment: just added base_path() to beginning, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added base_path() to beginning of my paths...

Answer (score 0):

base_path (http://api.drupal.org/api/base_path), if you use php code. 
In html case, just add "/", like: /sites/all/modules/pecapture/images/headline_dontmissout.jpg

One problem: if you work on subfolder (Drupal installed in internal folder of main site):  http://domain.com/subfoldersite, it will not correct, becase will remove "subfoldersite".